# Conversion problem: Large TIFF File to XYZ Format

Tags: type-conversion, tiff, gdal, osgeo, xyz

I am working with a TIFF file named CHELSAcruts_tmax_4_1981_V.1.0.tif (size: 97M).
I want to convert this file first to XYZ format and subsequently to CSV.

Attempts and Challenges
Online Converter Limitation: Initially, I attempted to use an online converter, but the file size exceeded the allowed limit.

Python Script for XYZ Conversion:
I found the following Python code snippet for conversion to XYZ format:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open("CHELSAcruts_tmax_4_1981_V.1.0.tif")
ds.GetGeoTransform()
xyz = gdal.Translate("dem.xyz", ds)
```

However, this approach has two major issues:

It takes an excessively long time to run.
It generates a file larger than my VM's free disk space (over 100 GB).
Observation of Zero Values: Upon closer inspection, I noticed the file contains many zero values, such as:

```
X Y Z
-179.99597222220001 83.9956937485000168 -32768
-179.987638888900022 83.9956937485000168 -32768
```

documentation: https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html
Attempt to Filter Zero Values: To address this, I tried filtering these values with the following code, but it was unsuccessful:

```py
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(-32768)
gdal.Translate("dem.xyz", ds, noData=-32768, creationOptions=["ADD_HEADER_LINE=YES"])
```

Using the code below, I found the image array's shape is (20880, 43200), which might be contributing to the file size issue.

```py
from osgeo import gdal
ds = gdal.Open('mytif.tif', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
rb = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
img_array = rb.ReadAsArray()
```

I tried to clear zero values with code below:

```py
import gdal_calc
import numpy as np

original_tiff = "/content/drive/My Drive/Kalmia/CHELSAcruts_tmax_4_1981_V.1.0.tif"
modified_tiff = "/content/drive/My Drive/Kalmia/modified_tiff.tif"

# Use gdal_calc.py to replace -32768 with NaN
gdal_calc.Calc("A*(A!=-32768) + nan*(A==-32768)", A=original_tiff, outfile=modified_tiff, NoDataValue=np.nan)
```

but it also works forever and gave no result

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DPpxNFgcE3d4W-7AemBN_zTtylibI9Na/view?usp=sharing

Given the large size, how can I efficiently convert it to XYZ and then to CSV format, while managing the size and zero-value issues?

Comment: Do you need the intermediate XYZ file or is the final CSV all that matters?

Comment: Any of them will fit. It's much easier to convert between CSV and XYZ.

Comment: Well, your file contains close to 1B data values - XYZ is not compressed and each line is about 50 bytes long, so the final file in ideal conditions should be about 50GB - maybe GDAL needs more to produce it - the file size is not surprising at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this doesn't make any sense to me for several reasons. The XYZ/CSV format will store the coordinates (as strings!) for every valid pixel, which is completely redundant for a regular grid like this. The exact same information can be retrieved using for example the geotransform (6 values) and file dimensions (2 values).

Storing it as string, uncompressed completely blows up the volume of data. Using a different format like (geo)parquet would already alleviate a lot of that.

Regardless, the snippet below shows how it can be done anyway. This does it all at once, so you'll need the memory to do so. It's of course possible to adapt the code and read the data in smaller chunks, and incrementally write them to the output file.

Using Pandas in this case, for convenience, probably also introduces it's own overhead on top of this. For a simple file format like this doing it manually is also feasible.

```py
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

#### Read raster data and metadata

```py
fn = "CHELSAcruts_tmax_4_1981_V.1.0.tif"

ds = gdal.Open(fn)

gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()

data = ds.ReadAsArray()
ys, xs = data.shape

ds = None
```

#### Filter nodata and create coordinates

```
valid = data != -32768
valid.sum(), valid.size

ulx, uly = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt, 0.5, 0.5)
lrx, lry = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt, xs-0.5, ys-0.5)

lats, lons = np.mgrid[uly:lry:gt[5], ulx:lrx+gt[1]:gt[1]]

# reduce memory a little...
lons = lons.astype(np.float32)
lats = lats.astype(np.float32)
```

#### write to csv

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    X=lons[valid],
    Y=lats[valid],
    Z=data[valid],
))

df.to_csv("CHELSAcruts_tmax_4_1981_V.1.0.csv", index=False)
```

As said, I would consider another approach where you at least store the data as binary, compressed, and without the redundant coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for the Python solution! It's been quite helpful, especially for filtering a small range of values.
.
After giving it some thought and reading answer, I concur that using Python to process the entire dataset might not be the most efficient approach for my specific needs.
My idea is:
Download a few files for different years.
From each one extract several thousands points (by longitude and latitude) with affiliated climatic variables and make following analysis.
Could you recommend any specialized software that are better suited for my task?

Comment: I think doing it with Python is fine, and several 1000's is very manageable (compared to this entire file). The `.ReadAsArray()` has arguments that allow reading small blocks or individual pixels. Using that to read those specific points should be very fast.
Higher level options are available, like xarray for example, that allow indexing the dataset with an array of points you need. That's more for convenience I'd say, since it'll still use GDAL (via rasterio) on the backend. 
Extracting points like this is basically a special case of "zonal statistics" but using points instead of polygons.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I'll go look at the documentation.
Thank you for your time, if I have any more questions, I will ask in the comments or in another question.